# Grammatical explanation of "He"

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales

I have never seen an explanation for the Spanish word "He".

Here is an example,

> **He** prometido guardar Tus palabras.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's exactly the same as "Have" in english. "He" is a verbal tense of the verb "haber".

(In your example, in english, "I **have** promised...")

Where is the doubt?

Maybe you are missing the subject, the person; in spanish you can skip it because it's implied in the verbal tense itself (Yo he, Tu has, Él ha, etc.), but it would be also correct to say "Yo **he** prometido guardar"...

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it may be hard to believe, and indeed after reading your answer it is hard for me to believe myself, but I have never been taught about haber or seen examples of it and so I was thinking of "he" in terms of a type of pronoun. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: I'm glad it helped to clarify it :)

Comment: It's not exactly the same as _to have_. You must Remember that _to have_ is used for _tener_, in some cases. Haber != Tener

Comment: He is talking about the "grammatical" aspect; I'm quite sure that he is aware of the meaning-difference you point.

Comment: @SergioVelásquez Actually, [Haber = Poseer = Tener](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?key=haber), though, to be fair, it's an old usage.

Comment: @MikMik my comment was wrong. I added a dot in the wrong place. It must be: _in some cases, haber !=tener_, just a clarification. Thanks for note that.

Answer (score 5):

You're thinking that "*He*" acts as the subject, aren't you? Well, it's not. It's the verb (In fact "*He prometido*" is the verb)

In Spanish you can apply an pronoun ellipsis when it acts as the subject.
For example, you can say:

> *Yo escribo una carta*

or

> *Escribo una carta.*

In your example (*He prometido*) you're using a compound tense of the verb "*Prometer*" (which is formed with the auxiliary tense of verb "Haber" + the past participle of verb "*Prometer*").

Here you can also apply the pronoun ellipsis rule if you want (which is very common to do it):

> *Yo he escrito una carta.*

or

> *He escrito una carta.*